# Bot Framework stuck in a Dialog Loop

Tags: c#, emulation, bots, botframework

I am using Bot Framework for one of my project. It seems to be stuck in a loop while processing reply from a PromptDialog.Confirm function.

```
namespace Genome
{
public class InitiateDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(ConversationStarted);
    }

    public async Task ConversationStarted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hi!");
        PromptDialog.Confirm(
            context: context,
            resume: ResumeAndPromptPlatformAsync,
            prompt: "Would you like to upload the document?",
            retry: "I didn't understand. Please try again."
            );
    }

    public async Task ResumeAndPromptPlatformAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Input Received");
    }
}
}
```

The execution of this code never reaches the ResumeAndPromptPlatformAsync function. Every-time I choose Yes/No at the PromptDialog.Confirm() the Bot Emulator loops back to start with ConversationStarted() and asks the same question again.

Comment: What version of the BotBuilder NuGet package are u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current code is correct, but there may have been an error in your previous code that caused the loop. Since bot framework saves the state automatically, you are still kind of stuck using the old code.

If you're using the facebook channel, type "`/deleteprofile`" to reset the state and start using your new code. If you're on the emulator, click either Delete Data or start a new conversation with a new user.

Also, your `ResumeAndPromptPlatformAsync` method must end with either `context.Wait` or `context.Done`, or else you're causing an exception which may also be a reason for the problem.

**Update:** I've run your code and it works as expected for me after I've added `context.Done(this);`. I'm using the emulator.

```
public async Task ResumeAndPromptPlatformAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
{
    await context.PostAsync("Input Received");
    context.Done(this);
}
```

Comment: I can repro the problem that is posted in this question (I have context.Done in my ResumeAndPromptPlatformAsync). It never gets to this method.
Looks like some bug in botframework. I'm facing this situation from yesterday

Comment: I've run the code and it works for me after I've added context.Done.

Comment: I added context.done and it handles with the issue, But I can't see the promptdialog in my bot window, Just plain text. Help!!!

Comment: The promptdialog **is** text.